# How to deal with Nonetype while fuzzy matching in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, fuzzywuzzy

So I am fuzzy matching two dataframes and want to find a match from the right table if it has a score of over 80. So for the ones that do not find a match over 80 it ends up with Nonetype which causes the script to fail. How can I handle this? I still want to know if it didn't find a match, so if I can display it as "None" or just blank I would prefer that.

```py
str2Match['key'] = str2Match.apply.(lambda x: process.extractOne(x['PRODUCT_NAME'], strOptions['REFERENCE_NAME'], score_cutoff=80)[0], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I got this working by just using a custom function like @pavan-chandaka suggested and put a try in it. For whatever reason, extractOne from fuzzywuzzy just breaks if it can't find a match, so I'm basically just passing the None value down to my dataframe with the try.

```py
 def namematch(pname, rname):
    try:
        match = (process.extractOne(pname, rname, score_cutoff=80)[0])
        return match
    except:
        return None
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look if this way of doing works.

From lambda call a custom function. Some what like

```
lambda x : customfunc(YOUR ARGUMENTS)
```

Inside the custom function call `extractOne`. As the `extractOne` returns `None`, when value not found, based on the return value polish the return for 'None' in the way you want.

```
def customfunc(YOUR ARGUMENTS):
    ret = process.extractOne(ARGUMENTS)
    if ret is None:
         #RETURN SOMETHING, YOU CAN MEAN NO VALUE.
    else:
         #RETURN THE VALUE.
```

Comment: Are you returning a dummy tuple from the custom function for None?

Comment: It is actually breaking on the ret = process.extractOne(ARGUMENTS) portion. So it seems like that function just is not able to have a value of None for some reason.

Comment: I was able to get it working by using a try instead of the if. However, it now just skips the rows with None and does not actually merge them in the dataframe at this point. So I have a new issue to figure out.